# How To Change Calendar's Size of Xceed WPF DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xceed

I am using Xceed DateTimePicker control. The problem is in its calendar size: when you enlarge the font in the control itself, the size and font of its pop-up calendar doesn't change. How do I change the size of the pop-up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `Style` of the `Calendar` within `DateTimePicker`. The trick is to wrap the calendar's `ControlTemplate` in a `ViewBox` of a suitable size, for instance, `Width` = `Height` = 300, as shown below:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" 
    x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DateTimePickerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlNormalBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="TimeWatermarkTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Focusable="False" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Focusable="False" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
                    <Border>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding AllowSpin}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ButtonSpinnerLocation="{TemplateBinding ButtonSpinnerLocation}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsUndoEnabled="True" MinWidth="20" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"/>
                                </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="_calendarToggleButton" Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                        <Binding Path="IsOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <xctk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                    <ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                                        <Binding Path="IsReadOnly" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <xctk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                            <xctk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome" CornerRadius="0" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}}}" RenderEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}}}">
                                                                <Grid>
                                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                    <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="5">
                                                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" Height="4" Width="7"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </xctk:ButtonChrome>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <ToggleButton.Visibility>
                                        <TemplateBinding Property="ShowDropDownButton">
                                            <TemplateBinding.Converter>
                                                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter/>
                                            </TemplateBinding.Converter>
                                        </TemplateBinding>
                                    </ToggleButton.Visibility>
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_calendarToggleButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calendar" BorderThickness="0" DisplayDate="2016-05-24" Style="{DynamicResource CalendarStyle1}"/>
                                        <xctk:TimePicker x:Name="PART_TimeUpDown" AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding TimePickerAllowSpin}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" ClipValueToMinMax="{Binding ClipValueToMinMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" FormatString="{TemplateBinding TimeFormatString}" Format="{TemplateBinding TimeFormat}" IsUndoEnabled="{Binding IsUndoEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Kind="{Binding Kind, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding TimePickerShowButtonSpinner}" Text="" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TimePickerVisibility}" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermark}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlMouseOverBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding AllowTextInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlSelectedBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <Viewbox Width="300" Height="300">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <xctk:DateTimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource DateTimePickerStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, it worked, but I had to remove the 
    <ToggleButton.Visibility>
part, as it gave me error like:
Error  The attachable property 'Converter' was not found in type 'TemplateBinding'.

Comment: why did you have to remove it?

Comment: It gives compile error: Error The attachable property 'Converter' was not found in type 'TemplateBinding'. Probably we are using different versions of library?

Comment: Thank you @jstreet, it worked when I raised .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way:

```
<Window x:Class="View.SampleDlg"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:View"  
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel"  
    ...
>
    ...
    <xctk:DateTimePicker 
        ...
        CalendarWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=CalendarWidth, Converter={viewModel:SizeConverter Percentage=200}, Mode=OneTime}"
    />
</Window>
```

Above used converter defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ViewModel
{
    public abstract class ConverterBase
        : MarkupExtension
        , IValueConverter
    {
        public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
    public class SizeConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public uint Percentage { get; set; }
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var num = (double)value;
            return (num * this.Percentage) / 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:wtk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

<wtk:DateTimePicker>
    <wtk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="wtk:DateTimePicker">
            <Setter Property="CalendarWidth"  Value="350"/>
        </Style>
    </wtk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
</wtk:DateTimePicker>
```

Just set CalendarWidth equals the size you like. Attention: CalendarHeight will be automatically calculated, cannot modify at this time.